# BFS' shortest path unweighted directed graph

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

The code I have is based on BFS and a little bit of Dijkstra and returns the shortest path of an unweighted directed graph as an integer. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code too see if anything could be changed or improved:

```
public int bfsshortestpath (V source, V target) {
    Map<V, Integer> dist = new TreeMap<V, Integer>();
    Map<V, V> prev = new TreeMap<V, V>();

    for(V v: adjlist.keySet()){
        dist.put(v, null);
        prev.put(v, null);
    }
    dist.put(source, 0);

    Queue<V> q = new LinkedList<V>();
    q.offer(source);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        V u = q.poll();
        if(u == target)
            break;
        q.remove(u);
        for(V neighbor: adjlist.get(u)){
            int a = dist.get(u);
            if(dist.get(neighbor) != null)
                continue;
            //BFS distance
            dist.put(neighbor, a + 1);
            prev.put(neighbor, u);
            q.offer(neighbor);
        }
    }

    List<V> s = new LinkedList<V>();
    V u = target;
    while(prev.get(u) != null){
        s.add(u);
        u = prev.get(u);
    }
    return s.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Advice 1**

```
for(V v: adjlist.keySet()){
    dist.put(v, null);
    prev.put(v, null);
}
```

This is \$\Theta(N)\$ and you don't really need it (see below). Also, **`TreeMap`** orders the keys (nodes) in a balanced binary search tree, which runs insertion/search/removal in worst case \$\Theta(\log n)\$ time, and you don't need it either: just use a **`HashMap`** with \$\Theta(1)\$ access, reading and writing.

**Advice 2**

In order to get rid of the initialization **`for`** in the above advice, you can do:

```
public int shortestPathLength(V source, V target) {
    Map<V, Integer> dist = new HashMap<V, Integer>();
    Map<V, V> prev = new HashMap<V, V>();
    Queue<V> q = new LinkedList<>();

    dist.put(source, 0);
    prev.put(source, null);
    q.offer(source);

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        V u = q.poll();
        if(u == target)
            return tracebackPath(u, prev);
        q.remove(u);
        for(V neighbor: adjlist.get(u)){
            if (!dist.containsKey(neighbor)) {                        
                dist.put(neighbor, dist.get(u) + 1);
                prev.put(neighbor, u);
                q.offer(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; // Target not reachable from source.
}

List<V> tracebackPath(V target, Map<V, V> prev) {
    List<V> s = new LinkedList<V>();
    V u = target;
    while(prev.get(u) != null){
        s.add(u);
        u = prev.get(u);
    }
    return s.size();
}
```

**Advice 3**

```
if(u == target)
```

Beware. I suggest you implement **`equals`** for whatever node type you use and change the above to

```
if (u.equals(target))
```

**Advice 4**

Since you need to map nodes to values in the **`HashMap`** s, you need to override a **`hashCode()`** as well in the graph node class.

**Concluding**

Suppose both target and source nodes are very close to each other. My implementation will return very fast because it does not have to run that nasty **`for`** loop.

Hope that helps.